# C++ compiler not working in cmd with visual studios and code blocks installed

Tags: c++, cmd

Hey everyone I have code blocks and visual basics installed and working with c and c++ but if I type g++ in developers cmd I get an error saying 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Go into the path of your codeblocks installation. Usually mingw toolchain is in there somewhere, find it with `dir/s/a g++*`. Once you know where it is just add that to your environment `path`.

Comment: When I run that command I get this: Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C472-9537
File Not Found

Comment: which codeblock download did you get? http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26. codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe and codeblocks-16.01mingw-nosetup.zip will come with mingw install, the others won't.

Comment: Note that visual studio has it's own C++ toolchain, `cl` and `link` which is different from mingw which is a gcc port to windows. Codeblocks can work with either toolchain if properly configured.

Comment: codeblocks-16.01-nosetup.zip was the only one that worked out of the box  ... codeblocks-16.01-setup.exe did not work when I installed

Comment: @greatwolf cl worked thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CodeBlocks is only an IDE, not a compiler, so use the [TDM-GCC Compiler](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/).

Download either the x32 or x64 version.

Then go through the setup, make sure you have *add to path*.

Once installed, you can then open Command Prompt (cmd), and type:

```
gcc -o output.exe files.cpp
```

*Note: I am not affiliated with TDM-GCC, I am just a happy customer.*

Comment: Will this mess up code blocks? I need to make sure everything runs in code blocks for my homework

Comment: Sorry about that, CodeBlocks is terrible when using from the console.

Comment: @WhozCraig I like to use sublime text but need to make sure everything I do for school will run with code blocks as well... I had this problem with a past class with C where something would run on codeblocks but not in the cmd

Comment: @BobDoeJoe it certainly would be terrible from the command line, since  since you don't use CodeBlocks from the console; you use the compiler toolchain from the console. CodeBlocks is just an multi-platform windowed IDE that wraps around your  actual compiler tools and debugger and gives you a UI to work with them. I think you're thinking of mingw; not codeblocks.

Comment: @Charlie in fact, you can use it from codeblocks as the compiler/linker/debugger of choice. Thus the recommendation from TDM.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahhh, yes, sorry about that.